# Opencv Subtraction costlier than multiplication

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to optimize the code of image-processing project

[image: Performance analysis done by VS2013 preview]

The analysis by VS2013 preview shows that subtract operation is costlier than multiplication(mul) operation.

In general multiplication is more costlier than subtraction right.?
If so why is not here.?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is potentially a combination of several factors.

- `t1` needs to be allocated during `subtract` call, and this takes a bit of time
- `t1` is quite possibly already in cache during `t1.mul(t1)` call, so accesses are faster
- I'm not sure what type `td` is, but I bet there is a `saturate_cast` going on for every element in the matrix when you add `1` to `td`; no casting needed in the `.mul()` calls
- subtract and multiply are both memory-bound operations, so for all but the smallest matrices, properly optimized code will hide the higher latency of the multiply instructions to achieve the same throughput for both operations, all else being equal (eg, caching, etc.)
- the `.mul()` calls are *in-place* operations, which has significant advantages for caching
- if this is a release build of the project, it's possible the optimizer rearranged code in such a way as to confuse the profiler about which time-consuming machine instructions correspond to which lines of code. You'd be surprised at the kind of deep wizardry involved in the optimized implementation of arithmetic operations on matrices in OpenCV.